# Rails_admin gem filter has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-admin

I'd like to be able to use the "Add Filter" dropdown so admins can search for posts that have been flagged a particular name.

My Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :post_flags
    has_many :flags, through: :post_flags
```

**config/initializers/rails_admin.rb**

```
config.model 'Post' do
    exclude_fields :rank, :embedded_url, :attached_picture, :updated_at

    object_label do
        "#{bindings[:post].user.name}"
      end

    list do
      field :text_content
      field :created_at
      field :user_id
      field :likes_number
      field :post_flags 
    end
 end
```

I've tried adding "searchable" to the field :post_flags to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to work through a similar problem.

Adding the following to your rails admin config should allow you to add a post_flag filter:

```
field :post_flags do
  searchable :name
end
```

However, you will get an SQL error when when you try to use the search filter.

We may have to hack RailsAdmin's MainController. Checkout this post: http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/07/hasmany-filter-in-railsadmin.html